# pandas groupby and countif in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
# -- create a dataframe 
list_columns = ['pet', 'grade', 'class']
list_data = [
    ['dog', 'A', 'A'],
    ['cat', 'A', 'C'],
    ['dog', 'B', 'E'],
    ['mouse', 'C', 'A'],
    ['dog', 'A', 'B'],
    ['cat', 'B', 'E'],
    ['dog', 'C', 'D'],
    ['dog', 'A', 'C'],
    ]
df_animals = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
df_animals.head()
```

I want for each pet to count how many `'A','B','C','D','E'` are in the column `grade` and how many in `class`.

Expected output would be

```
pet    status   grade   class
dog      A      3       1
dog      B      1       1
dog      C      0       1
dog      D      0       0
dog      E      0       1
cat      A      1       0
cat      B      0       0
cat      C      0       1
cat      D      0       0
cat      E      0       0
mouse    A      0       1
mouse    B      0       0
mouse    C      1       0
mouse    D      0       0
mouse    E      0       0
```

I tried to group and count by a specific item but does not work.
One idea was to count for each pet the A,B,C,D,E but it would be manual and don't think it's ok.
Can someone tell me how should I proceed?

```
df_animals.groupby('grade').apply(lambda x: (x=='A').count())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for reshape and then add missing categories by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = (df_animals.melt('pet')
               .pivot_table(index=['pet','value'],
                            columns='variable', 
                            aggfunc='size', 
                            fill_value=0)
               .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
      pet value  class  grade
0     cat     A      0      1
1     cat     B      0      1
2     cat     C      1      0
3     cat     D      0      0
4     cat     E      1      0
5     dog     A      1      3
6     dog     B      1      1
7     dog     C      1      1
8     dog     D      1      0
9     dog     E      1      0
10  mouse     A      1      0
11  mouse     B      0      0
12  mouse     C      0      1
13  mouse     D      0      0
14  mouse     E      0      0
```

Comment: So nice, I will read more about DataFrame.melt and reindex. Thank you